# PyDev equivalent for org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant

Tags: pydev

I try to extend my plugin to support Python as well as Java.

For Java I have the org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant extension point. So I can search for an Annotation in all CompilationUnits.

What is the equivalent or an alternative in PyDev for compilationParticipant. I know some concepts of PyDev are different. Maybe org.python.pydev.core.parser.IParserObserver?

For Python I want to search for Decorators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution my self, this is the extension point:

```
<extension
  point="org.python.pydev.parser.pydev_parser_observer">
  <parser_observer
        class="YourClazz">
  </parser_observer>
```

You have to impelement your own IParserObserver